# JpaRepository Supertype Subtype not working with save()

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring, spring-boot

I'm working with supertype/subtype entities using Spring-Boot and I've got everything working except the default save method in JpaRepository. Can someone look though my code and find my mistake? Thanks!

## Error

```
Hibernate: 
    /* insert com.pandera.wilson.model.TEST_Category
        */ insert 
        into
            test_post
            (post_body, post_created, descriminator, post_updated) 
        values
            (?, ?, 'category', ?) select
                scope_identity()
2016-12-12 15:17:33 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:127 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1093
2016-12-12 15:17:33 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:129 - The index 4 is out of range.
```

## TEST_POST.java - Supertype

```
package com.pandera.wilson.model;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * @author Austin Nicholas
 * @category Models
 */

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="descriminator", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Table(name = "TEST_post")
public abstract class TEST_Post {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "post_key")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long key;

  @Lob
  @Column(name = "post_Body")
  private String body;

  @Column(name = "post_Created")
  private Timestamp created;

  @Column(name = "post_Updated")
  private Timestamp updated;

  @Column(name = "descriminator")
  private String descriminator;

  @PrePersist
  protected void onCreate() {
    Timestamp time = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
    created = time;
    updated = time;
  }

  @PreUpdate
  protected void onUpdate() {
    updated = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
  }

  public TEST_Post() {
    super();
  }

  public long getKey() {
    return key;
  }

  public String getBody() {
    return body;
  }

  public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {

    JSONObject ret = new JSONObject();

    for (Method m : this.getClass().getMethods()) {
      if (m.getName().startsWith("get") && !m.getName().equals("getClass")) {
        try {
          ret.put(
              m.getName().substring(3),
              m.invoke(this)
          );
        } catch (JSONException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
            | InvocationTargetException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }

    return ret.toString(2);
  }
}
```

## TEST_Category.java - Subtype

```
package com.pandera.wilson.model;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

/**
 * @author Austin Nicholas
 * @category Models
 */

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("category")
@Table(name = "TEST_category")
public class TEST_Category extends TEST_Post {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "toolkit_key")
  private Toolkits toolkit;

  @Column(name = "category_title")
  private String title;

  @Column(name = "category_isVotable")
  private boolean isVoteable = false;

  public TEST_Category() {
    super();
  }

  public Toolkits getToolkit() {
    return toolkit;
  }

  public void setToolkit(Toolkits toolkit) {
    this.toolkit = toolkit;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public boolean isVoteable() {
    return isVoteable;
  }

  public void setVoteable(boolean voteable) {
    isVoteable = voteable;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {

    JSONObject ret = new JSONObject();

    for (Method m : this.getClass().getMethods()) {
      if (m.getName().startsWith("get") && !m.getName().equals("getClass")) {
        try {
          ret.put(
              m.getName().substring(3),
              m.invoke(this)
          );
        } catch (JSONException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
            | InvocationTargetException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }

    return ret.toString(2);
  }
}
```

## TEST_CommunityRepository.java

```
package com.pandera.wilson.repository;

import com.pandera.wilson.model.TEST_Post;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

/**
 * @author Austin Nicholas
 * @category Repositories
 */

@Repository
public interface TEST_CommunityRepository extends JpaRepository<TEST_Post, Long> {

}
```

## Code That Errors Out

```
TEST_Category category = new TEST_Category();
category.setTitle("Testing Title");
category.setToolkit(tk);
category.setBody("Testing body");

// I Autowired the repository
repository.save(category);
```

Comment: can you explain the error you encounter ?

Comment: @davidxxx **forgot to tag you